# TypeScript variadic ...args with return array of those types

Tags: typescript

I know that TypeScript [doesn't currently support variadic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), so I'm wondering how I can accomplish this in the mean time. I'm building a library so I don't mind jumping through some extra hoops as long as the end user doesn't have to deal with them.

Here's some simplified psuedocode:

```
type ConstructorBase<T> = {
  new (id: number): T;
  type: string
}

type Things = { [key: string]: Thing }

private _things: Things

getThings (id: number, ...ctors: ConstructorBase<Thing>): Thing[] { 
  return ctors.map((ctor) => this._things[ctor])
}
```

The idea is that the user can pass in some specially formed constructors and then get instances of those things associated with the id. This works great! However... the end user then has to cast those Thing[] to the expected outcome.

```
const [a, b] = get(15, ThingTypeA, ThingTypeB) as [ThingTypeA, ThingTypeB]
const [c, d, e] = get(15, ThingTypeC, ThingTypeD, ThingTypeE) as [ThingTypeC, ThingTypeD, ThingTypeE]
```

What I would like is for them to drop the `as ...` to dry up the end user code and for TypeScript to automatically infer the types.

**I would like something like this:**

```
getThings <T extends Thing[]> (id: number, ...ConstructorBase<T>): infer[]
```

**Experiments**

I've tried all kinds of variations I can think of and read through all of the TypeScript issues where people were talking about this, and just cannot figure it out. I am guessing I can do something with overloads but it seems like overloads require that the return types be the same, whereas I need to return variable length different tuples - it only sees the shortest implementation and not the longest.

```
getThing <T, U> (id: number, t1: ConstructorBase<T>, t2?: ConstructorBase<U>): [T, U?]
getThing <T, U, V> (id: number, t1: ConstructorBase<T>, t2?: ConstructorBase<U>, t3?: ConstructorBase<V>): [T, U?, V?] {
  // implementation
}
```

It's highly unlikely they'd ever want to go over six things, so if there's some kind of override I can offer that's fine, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use overloads, you probably want to reorder them so that the most specific overload (hardest to match) is first, and the most general overload (easiest to match) is last.  Optional parameters are easier to match, so you want signatures with optional parameters to come later in your list of signatures.  But you shouldn't need overloads.

You should be able to get the behavior you want in a single signature, as of TS3.1 by using [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to accept the input rest parameter and [mapped tuples/arrays](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to map the inputs to outputs.

Here is a possible type signature for you, with what I assume `ConstructorBase` is like:

```
type ConstructorBase<T> = new (id: number) => T;

declare function getThings<C extends ConstructorBase<any>[]>(
  id: number, ...ctors: C
): { [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends ConstructorBase<infer T> ? T : never }
```

Let's try it:

```
declare class Thing1 { constructor(id: number); }
declare class Thing2 { constructor(id: number); }

const things = getThings(123, Thing1, Thing2);
// const things: [Thing1, Thing2]
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Brilliant! This is magnificent, thank you for the reply. The signature does infer the expected types. Unfortunately, I can't get the body implementation to work. `ConstructorBase<T> also has `type: string`. Here's simplified body code: `return ctors.map((ctor) => this._things[ctor.type])`. It's telling me `Type 'Thing[]' is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends ConstructorBase<infer T> ? T : never; }'.` and I can't find any casting or anything that will correctly return it. I've tried with an object literal and array, etc., and am still stumped. Would you mind an example?

Comment: I updated the question with some additional implementation details.

Comment: You can always force an implementation to work either by using a single overload signature (and make the implementation signature very general) or by asserting the returned value `as any`.  Generic conditional types are very useful for call signatures (used by library users) but hard to assign to (used by library implementers) so you will often be forced to use assertions inside function implementations like this.

Comment: Oh man, I was casting everything *except* the final return value in the loop to `any`. Sometimes it's the simplest thing... Thank you for the help! I've learned so much about types from studying and researching your answer.